# Using invoke_map() or exec() on a data.frame

Tags: r, purrr

I have a dataframe, where different lines require different evaluations to compute a result. Each of these evaluations is implemented in a function, and the respective function to use is specified in a column in the dataframe. Here is a minimal example:

```
f1 = function(a,...){return(2*a)}
f2 = function(a,b,...){return(a+b)}

df = data.frame(a=1:4,b=5:8,f=c('f1','f2','f2','f1'))

#Expected result:
  a b  f result
1 1 5 f1      2
2 2 6 f2      8
3 3 7 f2     10
4 4 8 f1      8
```

With `pmap`, I am able to apply a function to each row of a dataframe, and I also read about `exec()` replacing `invoke_map()`, but none of my attempts to combine both seem to work because `exec()` only seems to work with lists:

```
df$result = purrr::pmap(df,df$f)
df$result = purrr::pmap(df$f,exec,df)
...
```

Is there a more elegant way than filtering the dataframe for each function, using pmap on each filtered dataframe and then binding everything back together?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I should mention that my dataframe has a lot of columns, and that the functions do not need the same arguments (e.g. some may be skipping ´´´a´´´, but require ´´´b´´´). Therefore I need a method where I don't need to pass the arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can do this with exec() and pmap()

```r
f1 <- function(a, ...) return(2 * a)
f2 <- function(a, b, ...) return(a + b)

df <- data.frame(a= 1:4, b = 5:8, f = c('f1', 'f2', 'f2', 'f1'))

require(purrr)
require(dplyr)

df |> mutate(result = pmap(list(f, a, b), exec))
#>   a b  f result
#> 1 1 5 f1      2
#> 2 2 6 f2      8
#> 3 3 7 f2     10
#> 4 4 8 f1      8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

PS. You might have been getting an error because you were passing named arguments to `exec()`. When you `pmap(list(f = "f1", a = 1, b = 1), exec)`, all the named arguments are passed to `...` in `exec(.fn, ...)`, because none of the list elements are named `.fn`.

In the above example, the list elements are passed without their names, and the first argument is therefore assumed (by `exec()`) to be `.fn`.

So you can use the method you suggested in conjunction with `base::unname()`:

```r
df |> relocate(f) |> unname() |> pmap(exec)
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 8
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 10
#
# [[4]]
# [1] 8
```

Whereas without `unname()` you will get at error:

```r
df |> relocate(f) |> pmap(exec)
# Error in .f(f = .l[[1L]][[i]], a = .l[[2L]][[i]], b = .l[[3L]][[i]], ...):
#   argument ".fn" is missing, with no default
```

Alternatively, you could rename `df$f` to `df$.fn` and pass the whole data.frame:

```r
df |> rename(.fn = "f") |> pmap(exec)
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 8
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 10
#
# [[4]]
# [1] 8
```

Comment: Hi. very interesting! Unfortunatly, I need to keep the names, as I can not be sure that the function takes the arguments in the same order as they are in the dataframe. Therefore, I need a method that handles the entire dataframe as such, without specifying arguments.

Comment: You could also just `rename(df, .fn = "f")`, then pass the entire data.frame as in the final example above.

Comment: This is it! I find it utterly strange to change a column-name to a keyword, but it works like charm

Answer (score 1):

Using `lapply()` over the rows, use `do.call()`

```
df$result = lapply(1:nrow(df), \(i) {
  do.call(df[i,"f"],as.list(subset(df[i,],select=-f)))
})
```

Output:

```
      a     b f     result
  <int> <int> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1     5 f1         2
2     2     6 f2         8
3     3     7 f2        10
4     4     8 f1         8
```

Comment: Nice workaround! Unfortunatly, I can not be sure that the functions take the arguments in the same order as they are in the dataframe. Therefore, I need a method that handles the entire dataframe as such, without specifying arguments.

Comment: how about my updated solution, which doesn't specify arguments?

Comment: Curiously, this approach might be faster, even though I like @CaptainHat's approach better, which is certainly more elegant (and elegance is what you asked for :) ). I wonder how each method performs on your actual data?

Comment: The rowwise()-method was indeed a bit faster, but this one is slower by an order of magnitude of ten. Thank you anyway!